# Insert data into two table at once using foreign key

Tags: android, sqlite

[Database Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBASn.jpg)

Above pic shows my database design. I want to insert data into these two tables. Some part into one table and some into second table using foreign key.
Also how can i delete data from two tables at once using foreign key.

```
public boolean insertToBlockList(String originatingAddress,String messageBody){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ORIGINATING_ADDRESS,originatingAddress);
        contentValues.put(MESSAGE_BODY, messageBody);
        db.insert(TABLE_BLOCK_LIST,null,contentValues);
        return true;
```

i wrote this code but doesn't work for me. kindly help.

Comment: You need to execute two queries to insert the data into two different tables.

Comment: first query to insert data into block_list table and second insert query to blocked_sms table

Comment: is idblocked_sms and id_blockedlist column  auto-increment ?

Comment: ok.  how to select and show data from these two tables using foreign key?

Comment: yes, its auto increment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*how to select and show data from these two tables using foreign key?*

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name;
```

Read more: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute two insert queries as told by @Prerak. However you have to use **sql transactions** for better result.

Comment: you're right. kindly also tell me how to select values from these two tables using foreign key? also tell me how to delete from one table which delete also into from second table? @Krish4906